# How can I change a payload array into a payload object in Node Red?

Tags: javascript, node-red, payload

In Node Red I have a message that has an array of three values as payload and I want to assign those values to three different properties of a payload object. How can I do that? 
Thank you

Comment: What have already you tried? There are a number of ways to do what you asked but the change node is probably a good starting point

Comment: Yes, I tryied with the change node setting three rules that move the msg.payload[0] into msg.payload.X, msg.payload[1] into msg.payload.Y and msg.payload[2] into msg.payload.Z but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61776319/edit) the question to show what you've done. That way you can format the code so it's easily readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly move the array elements to `msg.paload.X` because you can't add arbitrary fields to the existing array objects.

So you'll need to move the array to a temp field first. You will also have to only ever move the first (`[0]`) element in the array because it will get shorter on every move as the first element is pop'd from the array.

[image]

And finally delete the temp filed.